# Kotlin ArrayList and arrayOf have different behaviour for toString() method

Tags: kotlin

Why would the **Use case 1** (`arrayOf`) print the cryptic object address while `ArrayList` correctly understands and print the object properties. It is odd because, not just `ArrayList`, but `setOf`, `listOf` etc. all print the object properties correctly. It's seems `arrayOf` is somehow different.

```kotlin
data class Student(
    val id: String,
    val name: String
)

fun main() {
    val hello1 = Student("1", "A")
    val hello2 = Student("2", "B")

    // USE CASE 1
    val arr = arrayOf(hello1, hello2)
    println(arr)
        
    // OUTPUT: [LStudent;@37f8bb67

    //USE CASE 2
    val arr2 = ArrayList<Student>()
    arr2.add(hello1)
    arr2.add(hello2)
    println(arr2)
        
    // OUTPUT: [Student(id=1, name=A), Student(id=2, name=B)]    

}
```

Comment: An array is not a list and in Java (at least), an array does not have a `toString()` that dumps all items respectively their `toString()` methods. You will have to iterate/stream the items of an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is odd because, not just `ArrayList`, but `setOf`, `listOf` etc. all print the object properties correctly. It's seems `arrayOf` is somehow different.

Yes it is different, and maybe it's more different than you thought. I'm not exactly sure where the confusion occur so let me clarify some things.

To start with, `arrayOf` doesn't give you an `ArrayList`, it returns an `Array`, which is a different type. So there is no real reason to expect their `toString` to behave similarly. You might be confusing `arrayOf` with `arrayListOf`, which would indeed give you an `ArrayList`.

An `ArrayList` is a subtype of `List`, which is itself a subtype of `Collection`. `ArrayList` just happens to be a collection that is backed by an array (hence the name), but it doesn't make it an array itself. Also, there are many other types of lists.

The other builders you mention here (and that behave as you expect) return `Collection` subtypes:

- `listOf()` may return any subtype of `List` (including `ArrayList`)
- `setOf()` may return any subtype of `Set`

`Collections` have a nice `toString()` implementation that prints their elements. Arrays don't have a specific `toString()` method implementation, and only have the default one (this is legacy from Java), hence the type and memory address in the output.

However, you can use the [contentToString](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/content-to-string.html) extension on arrays to have a similar result as collections' `toString()` output:

```kotlin
val hello1 = Student("1", "A")
val hello2 = Student("2", "B")

val arr = arrayOf(hello1, hello2)
println(arr) // prints: [LStudent;@37f8bb67
println(arr.contentToString()) // prints: [Student(id=1, name=A), Student(id=2, name=B)]

val list = arrayListOf(hello1, hello2)
println(list) // prints: [Student(id=1, name=A), Student(id=2, name=B)]
```

Note that you shouldn't really use arrays in business code in Kotlin, as most stdlib APIs revolve around `List` and other collections. Arrays should probably be considered more low-level primitives in Kotlin.

Comment: May be worth stressing (since I can't see it stated explicitly, and suspect it's a source of confusion) that **`ArrayList` is a type of `List`**; it is _not_ an array (though it happens to use one internally). Similarly, `LinkedList` is a type of `List` that uses a series of linked nodes internally. The different `List` implementations vary in things like performance (memory, CPU), mutability, support for null values or random access — as indicated by their name and hence implementation — but as far as the language is concerned they're all just `List` (and often `MutableList`) implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Indeed given the name `arr2` for the second variable in the question, there may be a confusion with what an `ArrayList` is. I updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `arrayOf` is somehow different… It's (like in) Java, it does not have a `toString()` method, but in Kotlin, it has a `joinToString(…)` which you can easily use in order to *mimic* the built-in `toString()` of Java/Kotlin collections:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // prepare an array
    val hello1 = Student("1", "A")
    val hello2 = Student("2", "B")
    val arr = arrayOf(hello1, hello2)
    // join its items to a String with separator, prefix and postfix
    val joinedToString = arr.joinToString(", ", "[", "]")
    // and print it
    println(joinedToString)
}
```

Result:

```
[Student(id=1, name=A), Student(id=2, name=B)]
```

As mentioned (and answered) by @Joeffrey, you can do that with less code since there's `Array.contentToString()`:

The very same output as above can be achieved through

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // prepare an array
    val hello1 = Student("1", "A")
    val hello2 = Student("2", "B")
    val arr = arrayOf(hello1, hello2)
    // and print it using a specific (new?) method for it
    println(arr.contentToString())
}
```

Comment: No need for `joinToString` here, it's already built-in with `Array.contentToString()`

Comment: Oh, then I read an old documentation ;-) Do you know when it was introduced?

Comment: I think, Kotlin 1.1 (if we trust the KDoc), so quite some time ago. It's a wrapper around java's `Arrays.toString(..)` (at least on JVM). It was then re-introduced as an extension on nullable array types in Kotlin 1.4

Comment: I was reading [this](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/) but was not able to find the method… However, it's working and I am just editing the answer in order to mention it.

Comment: I think it's because it's an extension on arrays, defined in the collections package. So it doesn't appear as array methods. You can see the link to the doc of this method in my answer

Comment: That seems to be the (small) downside of the (great) idea of extension functions ;-) The docs get harder to read ;-)

Comment: I think that's a downside of the current implementation of Dokka. Perhaps it could be enhanced to add the documentation of extension functions to the html page of the class it extends (however, that could be problematic if it's not a class in the current library).

Comment: Yes, that would be problematic, but this downside is not a big one, it's a fair price for having extension functions. One should just be aware of *incomplete* docs, means, one should always have in mind there may be extensions.

Comment: I think Dokka already shows such extensions if they are declared in the same package. But indeed for true extensions provided by other modules or libraries, it's kind of expected that we can't see them

Comment: @deHaar If you're using a decent IDEA (IntelliJ being the most common), then you don't usually need to look at the docs — just type `myArray.` and see what pops up!

Comment: Thanks for the hint @gidds, that's what I usually do when I write code. But this time, I just read the docs ;-) Was not enough ;-)

Comment: @deHaar AIUI, support for autocompletion in IDEs is one of the main benefits of extension functions over stand-alone static utility functions (which is what you have to do in Java, and how extension functions are actually implemented in Kotlin/JVM…)